# Error "No such file or directory" when trying to execute spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've updated jdk and now when i'm trying to enter spark shell it gives the below error:

```
/home/orienit/work/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-class: line 86:  
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Any more details about versions? From which to which?

Comment: If you type `javac` and it will not run then `JDK` is not set, else you need to manually change your `JDK version` on your `Spark configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure spark points to the right java version:
1) go to `{spark-dir}/conf`
2) `cp spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh`.
3) edit 'spark-env.sh' and add `JAVA_HOME={JAVA_HOME_DIR}`
4) execute it - `./spark-env.sh`